# Sorting value data arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have the following array structure

```
[
    [ "April", "January", "March", "February" ]
    [ "10", "20", "5", "2" ]
]
```

The months are not in order and the numbers represent the data for each month. For example `January` has `20` items, `March` has `5` items etc.

Is there a way in JavaScript/jQuery I can keep the structure but ordered it as shown below?

```
[
    [ "January", "February", "March", "April" ]
    [ "20", "2", "5", "10" ]
]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change your array or arrays in to an object instead? It would seem to make more sense to have key/value pairs, given your requirements.

Comment: you could just sort the month array, and mirror the sort onto the 2nd array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using underscore...

```
var d = [ 
 [ "April", "January", "March", "February" ],
 [ "10", "20", "5", "2" ]
];

var months = {January:1, February:2, March:3, April:4}

var d = _.unzip(_.sortBy(_.zip(d[0],d[1]), function(a) { return months[a[0]] }))
```

Comment: This sounds pretty sweet. Thanks heaps Keith for the quick response and everyone else too. I really do appreciate the comments below. Turning it into an object sounds like a good suggestion too. Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have an array form:

```
[{January: 20}, {Feb:2}, {March:5}, {April, 10}];
```

Seems to me it is a key to value pair. Use the Object!

Answer (score 0):

As Rory suggests, it would be easier to keep the data together in a single object.

```
[
  {
    month: "January",
    items: 20
  }, { // next object }
]
```

However, the task can be solved pretty easily anyways:

```
// first, define the correct order of months:
var sortedMonths = [ "January", "February", "March", "April" ]

// your unsorted months and items:
var months = [ "April", "January", "March", "February" ]
var items = [ "10", "20", "5", "2" ]
var sortedItems = []
sortedMonths.forEach(function(month) {
  // find index of the month in the unsorted array:
  var index = months.indexOf(month)
  // get item at the index and insert into sorted array:
  sortedItems.push(items[index])      
})

console.log(sortedItems) // ["20", "2", "5", "10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, that puts them into an array of objects, sorts that array and then rebuilds the original structure:

```js
var data = [
    [ "April", "January", "March", "February" ],
    [ "10", "20", "5", "2" ]
];

// key for sorting months
var monthSortIndex = {January: 1, February:2, March:3, April:4, May:5, June:6, July:7, August:8, September:9, October:10, November:11, December: 12};

function getMonthSort(m) {
    var val = monthSortIndex[m];
    return val ? val: 13;
}

function sortMonthData(data) {
    // first put data into one array of objects
    var months = data[0];
    var numbers = data[1];
    months.map(function(value, index, array) {
        return {month: value, data: numbers[index]};
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
        return getMonthSort(a.month) - getMonthSort(b.month);
    }).forEach(function(obj, index) {
        data[0][index] = obj.month;
        data[1][index] = obj.data;
    });
}

sortMonthData(data);

// show result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a temporary array that's based on the index of each month, so it's automatically sorted.

It looks like this:

```
[{"month":"January","value":"20"},
 {"month":"February","value":"2"},
 {"month":"March","value":"5"},
 {"month":"April","value":"10"}
]
```

It's then a simple matter of looping through the array.

**Snippet:**

```js
var arr = [
      ["April", "January", "March", "February"],
      ["10", "20", "5", "2"]
    ],
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    tmp= [];

arr[0].forEach(function(mo, i) {
  tmp[months.indexOf(mo)]= {
    month: mo,
    value: arr[1][i]
  }
});

tmp.forEach(function(key, i) {
  arr[0][i]= key.month;
  arr[1][i]= key.value;
});

document.querySelector('pre').textContent= JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with map:

```
var data = [
    [ "April", "January", "March", "February" ],
    [ "10", "20", "5", "2" ]
]

var order = [ "January", "February", "March", "April" ]

order.map(function(name){
  var index = data[0].indexOf(name);
  return  [data[0][index], data[1][index]]
}).forEach(function(element, index){
  data[0][index] = element[0];
  data[1][index] = element[1];
});
```